# VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE when running VirtualBox with libvirt installed

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, libvirt

I'm running RHEL 6.4. I had been using a VirtualBox VM to run a simulator, but recently installed libvirtd for a different project. Now I want to run my VirtualBox VM again, but keep getting an error when I try to start the VM. I am guessing this is caused by conflicts with libvirtd but can't figure out how to get around it.

The error is:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine simulator.
VT-x is being used by another hypervisor. (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode.
Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).

Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

In an attempt to stop libvirtd and (re)start VirtualBox, I've tried mixing and matching these commands:

```
sudo service libvirtd stop
sudo /etc/init.d/libvirtd stop

sudo modprobe -r vboxdrv
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv start
```

No issues running these, but I still get the same error when trying to start my VM. I also tried running `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`, same issue. Any idea how to fix this?

(As an aside, I did try transferring the VM to virt-manager but it was causing weird issues with the display, so I'd prefer to just get VirtualBox working again.)

Comment: Are you still searching for a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, I've since switched jobs. I wasn't able to resolve this though, I think I just ended up creating a new VM in virt-manager.